# File.Copy() and UNC paths containing spaces

Tags: .net

Using `File.Copy(src, dest)` to copy a file from a UNC path containing spaces appears not to work. As I understand it, the File.Copy call should work fine with local paths with spaces. How can I make this work (short of using a shell to execute a 'copy' command)?

```
string srcPath1 = @"\\Host\Share\File_name.ext";  
string targetPath1 = @"C:\Temp\target1.file";
File.Copy(srcPath1, targetPath1);                 // OK

string srcPath2 = @"\\Host\Share\File name.ext";  // Note the space
string targetPath2 = @"C:\Temp\target2.file";
File.Copy(srcPath2, targetPath2);                 // File not found
```

The second File.Copy() in the above example throws a File Not found exception, claiming the path does not exist (the full path, i.e. not just up to the first space for example).

Comment: try string srcPath2 = @"\\?\Host\Share\File name.ext";

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you surround the paths in quotes?  In other words:

`string srcPath2 = String.Concat("\"", @"\\Host\Share\File name.ext", "\"");`

Comment: Is there any InnerException?  HRESULT?

Comment: No, it is just a normal file not found exception. The reason seems to be that UNC should somehow be URL (URI) encoded, but not quite. If I uri encode the path (except the slashes) i actually get it working now. Once I find a reference that confirms this I'll post that as an answer unless someone else can point me in the right direction.